# Serialize Old App Engine 'db' Queryset into JSON

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm just working on a rather dated project on App Engine that still uses the old 'db' model format instead of 'ndb'.

What would be the simplest way to serialize a 'db' query into JSON?

For example:

```
sections = Section.all() >>> JSON
```

All of the methods that I found from a google search use the `to_list` method of 'ndb' models.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

A quick read of the docs (you have done that ?) turns up `to_dict` https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions?hl=en#to_dict which allows you to transform a model entity to a dictionary.  Dictionaries can be transformed to JSON (unless they have Decimal values and a few other types, but I am sure you can work around that.).  Then just iterate over the query result, producing a list of dicts, which you can `json.dump(thelist)`

However if you have a lot of entities you will have to take some additional steps, but you can read the docs to work out that.